# How to update a variable in corona SDK?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a function, which  changes the variable from what it was to something new. I am using load-save .json tables to get and load data. How do I update the startmoneyTxt to display the new variable?

My function:

```
local function unlockBall(event)
  ballfirst = loadsave.loadTable("firstBall.json", system.DocumentsDirectory)
  currentMoney1 = loadsave.loadTable("cashTable.json", system.DocumentsDirectory)
  difference = currentMoney1 - ballfirstUnlock

   if(ballfirst == 0 and difference >= 0)then
    ballfirstID = 1

      loadsave.saveTable(ballfirstID, "firstBall.json", system.DocumentsDirectory)
      loadsave.saveTable(difference, "cashTable.json", system.DocumentsDirectory)

   end
end
```

My code which should be updated:

```
currentMoney = loadsave.loadTable("cashTable.json", system.DocumentsDirectory)
startmoneyTxt= display.newText("$ "..currentMoney.." " , 0,0, "Helvetica", 20)
sceneGroup:insert(startmoneyTxt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want change text use

```
startmoneyTxt.text = "Your text here"
```

*Note*: As names `saveTable` and `loadTable` imply functions are indent to save/load tables. So you can use one file to save/load multiple values.

I use loadsave module to save/load setings in my game [The  Great Pong](https://github.com/ldurniat/The-Great-Pong/blob/master/preference.lua).